# How to Parse a Position Based .txt File in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, txt

I have a .txt file that contains thousands of position based lines and i have to convert it into a dataframe.

Here it is two lines for example:

0000000000000010010130001026001026000005032210128866FCA
0000000000000020010130001026001026000005033210128867FCA

The strings will always contains 56 characters and the fields (df columns) always have the same size, eg:

```
Field 1 = [0:14]
Field 2 = [15:31]
Field 3 = [32:35]
Field 4 = [36:53]
Field 5 = [54:56]
```

Expected Result:

| Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000000000 | 1001013000102600 | 1026 | 000005032210128866 | FCA |
| 00000000000000 | 2001013000102600 | 1026 | 000005033210128867 | FCA |

EDIT: I just found out that my problem is bigger than i thought. If a certain condition is met, i can have 2 row that contains different string sizes that refers to the same row and they should be merged into the same string to became a single line.

0000000000000090010130001026001026000009300220707238FBC  2202209012022090120221130BOV

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pandas [fixed-width formatted reader](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) to good effect here!

```py
>>> colspecs = [(0,14), (14,30), (30,34), (34,52), (52,56)]
>>> pd.read_fwf("input.txt", colspecs=colspecs, header=None, index=None, dtype="str")
                0                 1     2                   3    4
0  00000000000000  1001013000102600  1026  000005032210128866  FCA
1  00000000000000  2001013000102600  1026  000005033210128867  FCA
```

Comment: Altough your solution worked up nicely, i just found out my problem is bigger than i thought. If a certain condition is met, i can have 2 row that contains different string sizes that refers to the same row. I'll edit my post to include more info.

Comment: 1) if you have a fundamentally new Question, ask a new Question! 2) what should the result be? this might be fixed by first processing the file contents (perhaps into an `io.TextIOWrapper` or similar, which will behave like a file https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) and cleaning up the short lines (possibly removing them, keeping their line index and reinserting them later or merging them by whatever rules you define in advance)